# How to block the invoice creating in virtuemart 2.0 in paypal payment plugin

Tags: php, paypal, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I need to block the invoice creating code in Virtuemart 2.0 Paypal payment method plugin.
How it possible ?  please help me to do this.

Comment: Did you mean Order entry after successfull payment or Just need to block the invoice email send to the customer ?

Comment: Yes..I mean the invoice creation is only after the successful payment of Order entry.

Comment: Which payapl plugin you are using default one with VM or another one that have payment option within your site?

Comment: Presently i am using default paypal plugin with VM.

Comment: Then you can't block order creation before payment success. The default VM Paypal is works like, create order -> send to payapl -> success confirm order else cancel order

Comment: If you need to place the order only after the successfull payment you have to check paypal plugin that pays within your site ie, accepting card details in your site and process via CURL .

Comment: I don't need to block the order creation. I only need to insert the order details to invoices table only if the order status is confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

In your Payment plugin section on backend.

Go to Paypal Payment option you will have three options.

```
PayPal Waiting ->  Pending
PayPal Confirmed -> Confirmed
PayPal Cancelled -> Cancelled
```

here the waiting status you can consider while creating order time,

when the order creates it trigger the Paypal payment plugin with `Pending` status you can trace that event on,

```
plugins\vmpayment\paypal\paypal.php
```

In this `plgVmConfirmedOrder()`  function get control with `Pending` you can check whether status and avoid DB Query their.

Also triggering this function from `cart.php helper` file inside `confirmedOrder()`

Hope its helps.

Comment: I got another option,That is in the administrator/components/com_virtuemart/models/orders.php and the function createInvoiceNumber() add a new condition if($orderDetails['order_status'] == 'C'), In this the invoice created only if the order status is confirmed

Comment: When i block the createInvoiceNumber() using this condition if($orderDetails['order_status'] == 'C'), The order email not sending for the pending status orders. please give a solution to solve this issue.

Comment: instead of using  if($orderDetails['order_status'] == 'C') check the paypal status too ie, once payment failed then only comes to this condition so already processed order do not enter inside condition

Comment: Another option is just create an additional order status for failed orders and check that condition only then it will not effect any other condition